# $\operatorname{Gal}(f)$ is not commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> If $f$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with roots in $\mathbb{R}$ and also in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$. Show that the Galois group is not commutative.

I tried to do using the fact that conjugation is an element of Galois group and is represented as an even number of 2 cycles in $S_{\partial(f)}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume commutative.

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be any root of $f$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R}$ another root. Let $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(f)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha) = \beta$. Let $\tau$ be complex conjugation. By commutativity of the Galois' group, $$\overline{\beta} = \tau(\sigma(\alpha) = \sigma(\tau(\alpha)) = \beta$$ so $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, contradiction

Comment: Nice answer!!!!